Ubuntu 23.10 pulseaudio on pipewire bluetooth pairing works but re-connection with external bluetooth speaker fails
Edit - June 11th 2024
I've updated my 23.10 to 24.04 LTS and with it came kernel 6.8. All my stated bluetooth problems below are solved now.
TL;DR
(X)Ubuntu 23.10 and 22.04: Airpods work, external bluetooth speaker (Logitech UE Boom) pairs, but fails to re-connect after.
In more detail:
Interestingly, I have the same issue with a specific external bluetooth speaker on both my Ubuntu 22.04 (clean install) and 23.10 (clean install). Also the 23.10 uses pulsaudio with pipewire (libspa-0.2-bluetooth), while the 22.04 uses only pulseaudio (pulseaudio-module-bluetooth). Xubuntu uses blueman-manager on both systems.
What works is, removing the external speaker from my bluetooth device list and newly pairing it. It pairs, It connects, I can listen to music. The problem is as soon as I disconnect it and try to re-connect I get the: "Connected", "Disconnected", "Connected", "Disconnected" etc. problem.
The Airpods, however, have no problem at all. Connecting, disconnecting, re-connecting everything works perfectly fine (on both systems).
Given that I have the exact same problem on both systems, I'd rule out pulseaudio / pipweire setup. But could it be that it's a config issue, where the config for pairing differs the config for connecting?
Outputs from the 23.10 system:
kernel
6.5.0-35-generic

hardware (Lenovo X1 Carbon):
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz [8086:0070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. Prometheus MIS Touch Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b67d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

software:
$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 82
Tile Size: 65472
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.79)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_6__source
Cookie: d4d1:afdf

After initial successful pairing & connecting (music works, yay):
2024-05-24T10:58:03.793879-07:00 x1 wireplumber[3386]: RFCOMM receive command but modem not available: AT+BTRH?#015
2024-05-24T10:58:03.794556-07:00 x1 bluetoothd[903]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-source profile connect failed for 88:C6:26:64:D6:AC: Device or resource busy
2024-05-24T10:58:03.887209-07:00 x1 wireplumber[3386]: Failed to register battery provider. Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod
2024-05-24T10:58:03.887631-07:00 x1 wireplumber[3386]: BlueZ Battery Provider is not available, won't retry to register it. Make sure you are running BlueZ 5.56+ with experimental features to use Battery Provider.
2024-05-24T10:58:03.933376-07:00 x1 kernel: [ 2069.907846] input: UNICORN BOOM (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input21
2024-05-24T10:58:03.953823-07:00 x1 wireplumber[3386]: RFCOMM receive command but modem not available: AT+CSRSF=0,0,0,1,0,0,0#015

After disconnecting / reconnecting (no connecting, no music, sniff):
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service 
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-05-24 10:23:45 PDT; 32min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 903 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18641)
     Memory: 3.1M
        CPU: 661ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─903 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 24 10:40:32 x1 bluetoothd[903]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to 88:C6:26:64:D6:AC: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)
May 24 10:40:54 x1 bluetoothd[903]: src/profile.c:ext_connect() Hands-Free Voice gateway failed connect to 88:C6:26:64:D6:AC: Permission denied (13)
May 24 10:40:55 x1 bluetoothd[903]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to 88:C6:26:64:D6:AC: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)
May 24 10:40:55 x1 bluetoothd[903]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-source profile connect failed for 88:C6:26:64:D6:AC: Device or resource busy
May 24 10:40:59 x1 bluetoothd[903]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to 88:C6:26:64:D6:AC: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)
May 24 10:48:35 x1 bluetoothd[903]: src/profile.c:record_cb() Unable to get Hands-Free Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
May 24 10:48:41 x1 bluetoothd[903]: src/profile.c:ext_connect() Hands-Free Voice gateway failed connect to 88:C6:26:64:D6:AC: Permission denied (13)
May 24 10:48:42 x1 bluetoothd[903]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to 88:C6:26:64:D6:AC: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)
May 24 10:48:42 x1 bluetoothd[903]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-source profile connect failed for 88:C6:26:64:D6:AC: Device or resource busy
May 24 10:48:45 x1 bluetoothd[903]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to 88:C6:26:64:D6:AC: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)

I'd really appreciate any help with a possible configuration, or other workaround solution to avoid re-pairing every time I switch off my bluetooth speaker. Thanks for your help!

Sounds like the issue might be with the speaker and not the OS or computer hardware at all.

But the speaker always works fine the first time pairing/connecting it. It only doesn't work if it's already paired and you want to reconnect.
